# Which method is being called after popBackStack from fragD to fragA?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on fragment transaction so  my firts fragA is added in activity and onresume method is called in fragA Where i hit the api.Then after that I add the further fragments:

fragA => fragB => fragC => fragD

I would like to return to fragA from fragD on the button click.So when I returned to fragA no onResume method was called.so how do i call this from frag D to A?
I used below code

In FragD
on Button click I used the below code

getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

So is there any method being called in a previous fragment(fragA) after popBackStack() in fragD ?

Comment: Do you add fragments in backstack or just replace it?

Comment: @JeelVankhede I add the fragments.

Comment: And do you add your fragments to backstack?

Comment: @JeelVankhede yes